# Sphinx search entire field but not begin/end

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to match a field that contains all the words in a phrase but so far have only been able to use ^ and $ to do it. For instance

```
^Word1 Word2$
```

Returns a record named `"Word1 Word2"` but not `"Word3 Word1 Word2"`.

However what I want in fact is also `"Word2 Word1"`

So I get how to use the ^ and $ to mean start and end of the field but that forces the words I put in to be in particular order. Clearly I could also search for "Word2 Word1" but it gets more complex (3+ word terms, etc)

Is there a way to tell sphinx to look in an entire field in any order. In other words I want `"Word1 Word2"` to match `"Word1 Word2"` and `"Word2 Word1"` but not `"Word3 Word2 Word1"`

Answer (score 0):

Well can use NEAR/ or the proximity operator to require the words ajoining(but in any order), but there isnt really a good way to require 'entire field'.

Closest would probably to use index_field_lengths, then get the field len can use in a custom ranking expression. But if multiple fields in your index will be very tricky to implement.